# Expectation value with half binomial distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

I consider a binomial distribution with $N$ draws and the typical probabilities $p$ and $q=1-p$ and expectation value $\mu=Np$.

I now need to compute the expectation value of the function
\begin{align}
f(n)=\begin{cases}
a (n-\mu)^3 & n<\mu\\
b (n-\mu)^3 & n>\mu
\end{cases}\,.
\end{align}
If $a=b$, I would just compute the skewness, which is well-known for the binomial distribution, but I'm essentially interested in a skewness if the underlying function has small jump in its derivative.

Of course, I can write formally that the solution to my problem is
\begin{align}
\langle f\rangle=a \sum_{n<\mu} \binom{N}{n}p^n q^{N-n} (n-\mu)^3+b\sum_{n>\mu} \binom{N}{n}p^n q^{N-n} (n-\mu)^3\,,
\end{align}
but this is not super explicit. In fact, I would mostly like to know the leading order term and how it scales with $N$. From the definition of the skewness, I know that for $a=b$, I simply have
\begin{align}
\langle f\rangle=a Npq(q-p)\,.
\end{align}

**My question: What is $\langle f\rangle$ for $b\neq a$ up to order linear in $N$ (lower orders can be ignored)?**

I tried to approach this problem by doing the equivalent calculation for a normal distribution. For this, I just assume $a=b$ for the binomial, so that for $n>\mu$, I just integrate against a Gaussian. This yields
\begin{align}
\langle f\rangle_{\mathrm{correction}}=(b-a)\int^\infty_{\mu}\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} e^{\frac{1}{2}(\frac{n-\mu}{\sigma})^2}(n-\mu)^3dn=(b-a)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sigma^3=(b-a)\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\sqrt{Npq}^3\,.
\end{align}
This is clearly a part of the correction (and even scales dominantly compared to the skewness), but I couldn't figure out if there is an additional correction of order $N$ due to the difference between binomial and Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Compute the leading order terms of the [Edgeworth series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edgeworth_series) or similar.

Comment: Thank you. This was a crucial hint and works perfectly!